# Laravel Eloquent: Detect is empty or count

Tags: laravel, object, collections, eloquent, laravel-5.6

The main question is how to detect an eloquent collection result is empty or not, what laravel suggest to recognize this?

I have two different questions about this, maybe they are related to each other or not,

**The first:**

> How can i get the result of `$result = $user->delete()` OR `$result = $user->save();` methods?

I mean check if the operation Done or NOT

Is it correct or sufficient to use `if($result){...}` for this?

**The second:**

> What is the correct way to get `$result =User::where(conditions)->get()` is empty or not?

Please show me the correct way that cover all cases,

Comment: For the first, always consult the API documentation or PHPDoc block.  It should say what return type/value to expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#1**

```
if($user->delete())
  return true;
    else
  return false;

if($user->save()){
  return true;
}
```

**#2**

To determine if there are any results you can do any of the following:

```
if (!$user->isEmpty()) { }
if ($user->count()) { }
if (count($user)) { }
```

**Notes / References**

http://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_first
http://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_isEmpty
http://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_count
http://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_count

Answer (score 3):

Delete and save are synchronous so unless an exception is thrown it's a safe bet they are done.

For the 2nd question, you can do:

```
User::where(conditions)->count();
```

There's also `isEmpty` and `isNotEmpty` on colllections.

Another way is using exists/doesntExist:

```
User::where(conditions)->exists(); // or doesntExist()
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, it's ok. Or you can use

```
if($user->delete()) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

2) You can use function `empty()`

```
$result = User::where(conditions)->get()
if (!empty($result)) { 
 // if it is not empty, do the following...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First**

`$user->delete()` and `$user->save()` both are return true or false. So you can do like that.

```
if($user->save())
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

**Second**

According to your statement.

```
$result = User::where(conditions)->get();    
if(count($result)
     return true;
else
     return false;
```